# spring repository transactions in service transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I'd have 1 question:
the implicit methods in spring data jpa repositories (findAll, save, etc.) are `@Transactional`.
So in this case:

```
@Transactional
public void atomicTransaction() {
    repository1.save(entity);
    repository2.save(entity);
}
```

if repository2#save fails and rollbacks, is it propagated to the `atomicTransaction()` so that reposotory1#save also rollbacks?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the fundamental principles of transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The `save` method of `jpa` repository will open a micro-transcation unless it is already in a transactional context. In your case you have annotated the method with `@Transactional`, so what that means is that it will be seen as an atomic unit of work, that is it either executes **completely** or it **rollbacks** in case of errors.

Comment: so the exception triggering the rollback in the save method is "rethrown" and triggers rollback in the main transaction? Because there would have to be explicitly set the propagation property on the nested transactions, as far as I know

Comment: @fooBar I thought it was clear, bur maybe not. In the answer I said that if you annotate the method with Transactional no other separate transactions for save methods will be created. If some exception occurs, this main transaction will be rolled back.